# Create Sub Folders within a specific Sub Folder

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have a directory being created with todays date and a user choice of three integers. 
Within this directory I have a number of sub folders being created that are named ARI,Ale, Cdl, MXF, Reports etc etc

I want to create more subfolders but only for one sub folders the 'ARI" folders.

How do I specify that I want Folders named "Main Unit" and "Second Unit" to be created ?

Below is what I have done so far - appreciate any help :)

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import datetime


try: #Handle Python 2.7
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    pass

deepfolders = ("Main Unit", "Second Unit")
subfolders = ("ari", "sound", "cdl" , "mxf" , "h264" , "reports" , "ale")
parent_format = "{0:03d}_{1:%y%m%d}_Unit_Project"
path = ('/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/thenightfactory/Documents')
path2 = ('/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/thenightfactory/Pictures')
os.chdir(path)

from datetime import datetime

weekday = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%A")

print ("")
print ("Hello, Happy " + weekday + "! Please Select A Shooting Day To Create Today's Folders:")
print ('\033[91m' + "This will only work until midnight and can only be three integers eg. 023" + '\033[0m')
print("=" * 80)

while True:
    try:
        shootnum = (int(input("Enter today's shoot number > ")))
    shootnum = (str(shootnum))
    shootnum = int(shootnum[:3])

    successful= True
    if successful:
        print ("")
        print ('\033[91m' + "Folder's Have Been Created, Good Luck Shooting!" + '\033[0m')
        print ("")
    break
    except ValueError:
        print('\033[91m' + "Invalid number, please try again." + '\033[0m')

import datetime 

parentpath = parent_format.format(shootnum, datetime.datetime.now())
if not os.path.exists(parentpath):
    os.makedirs(parentpath)
    for subfolder in subfolders:
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(parentpath, subfolder))

os.chdir(path2)
parentpath = parent_format.format(shootnum, datetime.datetime.now())
if not os.path.exists(parentpath):
    os.makedirs(parentpath)
    for subfolder in subfolders:
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(parentpath, subfolder))
```

Comment: why don't you just change directory to `ari` with `os.chdir` and create  them with `os.mkdir( NAME)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a (semi) general solution, one way to go about the problem, is to just join all bits together, since join can take more than one argument. Thus, add an extra loop when running in the `'ari'` subfolder as:

```
deepsubs = ['ari']
if not os.path.exists(parentpath):
    os.makedirs(parentpath)
    for subfolder in subfolders:
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(parentpath, subfolder))
        if subfolder in deepsubs:
            for deepfolder in deepfolders:
                os.makedirs(os.path.join(parentpath, subfolder, deepfolder))
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach to this would just have a check on subfolder value and descend to it and create the required directories.

```
parentpath = parent_format.format(shootnum, datetime.datetime.now())
if not os.path.exists(parentpath):
    os.makedirs(parentpath)
    for subfolder in subfolders:
        pwd = os.getcwd()
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(parentpath, subfolder))
        # Checking in list in case you want todo same for multiple dir
        # else just eqality check would do
        if subfolder in ['ari']:
            os.chdir(os.path.join(parentpath, subfolder))
            for df in deepfolders:
                os.makedirs(os.path.join(parentpath, subfolder, df))
            os.chdir(pwd)
```

Please let me know if this is not what you were looking for.

Comment: you use `os.path.join(parentpath, subfolder)` twice after assigning it to `subdir`

Comment: :-) And I was using it where I shouldn't have. Fixed.

Comment: When I try this I get a folder structure consisting of  023_170731_UNIT_Project > Ari > 023_170731_UNIT_Project > then 023_170731_UNIT_Project (with the other folders) and ari (with the main unit and second unit folders)

Comment: Did you add it your existing code or replacing your existing code with it?

Comment: I replaced it - I'm guessing I should be adding this to the code then ?

Comment: There was an error. I was coming back one level below while changing dirs. However, I think we can just not change dir itself.